# Importing JSON into interface with discriminated unions

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with importing json into interface with discriminated union pattern used. The error message I get on the assignment of imported json to typed variable in ts is that `type: string` is not assignable to `type: "A"`. I understand what it is trying to tell me and using type cast `as Card[]` is a simple workaround. I would rather know id it's possible to solve this correctly without the cast so the typescript can correctly check the imported json.

Here are the interfaces:

```
// cards.tsx
export type CardType = "A" | "B";

export interface BaseCard {
    type: CardType;
    name: string;
}

export interface ACard extends BaseCard {
    type: "A";
    foo: string;
}

export interface BCard extends BaseCard {
    type: "B";
    goo: string;
}

export type Card = ACard | BCard;
```

Here is the code that gives the error:

```
import { Card } from './cards.tsx';
import Cards from './cards.json';

const cards: Card[] = Cards;
```

Example json:

```
[
    { "type": "A", "name": "AName", "foo": "FOO" },
    { "type": "B", "name": "BName", "goo": "GOO" }
]
```

Comment: Since typescript does not infer literal tyeps for json, you will need to use a type assertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error message I get on the assignment of imported json to typed variable in ts is that type: string is not assignable to type: "A". I understand what it is trying to tell me and using type cast as Card[] is a simple workaround.

Here is an equivalent simplification of the error:

```
type Card = {
    a:"A",
    value: number
}

const failJSON = {
    a: "A",
    value: 123
}

const fail: Card = failJSON; // Error: type string not assingable to type "A"
```

## Fix

If it was not json you would assert the inference at the point of creation:

```
type Card = {
    a:"A",
    value: number
}

const passJSON = {
    a: "A" as "A", // NOTICE!
    value: 123
}

const fail: Card = passJSON; // OK
```

But since it is a JSON file you cannot add an assertion in there. You only option is to assert `as Card[]` as you have already figured out.

## Reason

TypeScript infers `string | number | boolean` etc. instead of literals for objects.

Comment: Well, that's a shame that feature like this is no yet present. I wasn't able to find any more information about it sadly.

Comment: I have it documented in the inference section in literal types : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html 